# How to programmatically draw arcs between cities on a global map?

Tags: dictionary, diagram

I have a series of cities that I need to programmaticly draw arcs between on a global map.  The arcs also have to be labeled with a series of values.  Output needs to be png or something similar (i.e. I am not looking for a javascript solution.)

Any suggestions on ways of doing this?  I can choose language or tool (so long as it is free).

Comment: You want to programmatically draw lines on an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found one that will work perfectly myself.

http://scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Maps

Answer (score 0):

From your description, any language would do. Java, Python, C# etc. They each have graphics libraries that make it easy to draw lines and text and output images.

Answer (score 0):

Processing might fit your bill

http://processing.org/exhibition/